# Download Youtube Videos

Tags: web-access, user-interface, video

Is there a way to display or download youtube videos in Mathematica.

Youtube is HTML5 enabled so I am hopeful there might be an easy way.

Comment: It's too late here to get into it but you might check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4420154/1463976

Comment: Relevant discussion: [Playing with YouTube from Mathematica](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1484511)

Answer (score 7):

There is nice general writeup made by @b3m2a1:

- [Playing with YouTube from Mathematica](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1484511)

The "display" part of the question is very easy. In the Cloud version of notebooks which can be accessed here:

https://www.wolframcloud.com

You can use [EmbeddedHTML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmbeddedHTML.html) to embed a video right into a Cloud notebook:

```
EmbeddedHTML[ "<iframe width='854' height='510' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/60P7717-XOQ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"]
```

which will look like:

[image]

also take a look at:

- [Embedding YouTube videos into a Cloud Notebook](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/426362)
- [Accessing a YouTube video in a notebook](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/317613)

Comment: Please could you check your last link. It goes nowhere for me. Thanks

Comment: @Hugh it is a bug we should fix soon. But I added 1 more link [Playing with YouTube from Mathematica](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1484511) for you - I hope it is helpful.