# Can Mathematica capture a Vimeo video?

Tags: import, video

I'd like to capture or download a Vimeo video (only for personal use) in Mathematica.
Essentially, a yoga video I'd like to play at a slower speed as I try to learn the sequence.

I've found some dated discussion on this site of some related things:

[How to connect to a video stream?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87848/how-to-connect-to-a-video-stream)

[Importing videos in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161/importing-videos-in-mathematica)

[Download Youtube Videos](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71375/download-youtube-videos)

but none of this gives me an approach that looks workable.

Version 12.1 does have an "Experimental" function: `Video[]`, which can take a URL, e.g.,

```
    Video["https://vimeo.com/149138736"]
```

Which gives me the error:

[image]

Unfortunately the function does not appear to identify the video embedded within the URL.

```
    VideoQ[Video["https://vimeo.com/149138736"]

    False
```

Thoughts and guidance appreciated.

Comment: Video content is almost never exposed directly through a URL. Why not use something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimeo-video-downloader/cgpbghdbejagejmciefmekcklikpoeel?hl=en) to download the video?